# I am found everywhere and yet nowhere

Tags: riddle

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

What Am I?

Hint:

> I am **alive** until I briefly am not.

Hint 2:

> line 3: Each line is a reference to an aspect of me. can you catch 'em all?

Hint 3:

> line 4: Bravely fought, The tears saved. I was also secretly the escape from the chamber.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not a native English speaker, but I'll do my best:
Is it

> a Phoenix?

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> I'm thinking of reborn

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> Phoenix dies in flames but is reborn from its ashes

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> Phoenix tears are known to be a healing substance

Comment: See if you can figure out what all of the lines are. if you can figure out all the lines I will mark you as the answer :)

Comment: The Buddhist remark really threw me off this riddle, but this makes so much sense. Good job +1

Comment: Hint 3 would refer to `Uneel Cbggre.  Nsgre gur 'Punzore bs Frpergf' onggyr, gur curbavk fnirq Uneel jvgu vgf grne naq gura pneevrq rirelbar bhg`.  I'm not sure about Hint 2's Pokemon reference since `Gurer vf n curbavk cbxrzba [Zbygerf] ohg NSNVX vg qbrfa'g tenag jvfurf`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Concerning the Pokemon thing `Ub-bu vf gur orggre bcgvba, vg'f obgu cubravk yvxr (rira vs vg vfa'g ba sver, arvgure vf Snjxrf sebz Uneel Cbggre) naq vg'f fnvq vs lbh frr bar, lbhe qrrcrfg qrfver jvyy pbzr gehr, be fbzrguvat yvxr gung.` Edit: Sorry, my copy paste didn't agree with me.

Comment: Also concerning line three and the Pokemon clue, `Naq gur "bccbfvgr" cneg bs yvar 3 jbhyq ersre gb Yhtvn, gur bgure Tra 2 yrtraqnel oveq, juvpu fyhzoref ng gur obggbz bs gur bprna VVEP.`

Comment: Also, for the title, it's likely a reference to the face that `gur cubravk vf irel cbchyne va svpgvba, fb vg'f sbhaq pbzzbayl va tnzrf, zbivrf, naq obbxf. Ubjrire, gur cubravk qbrf abg rkvfg va gur erny jbeyq, fb vg'f "rireljurer" va cbc phygher, ohg "abjurer" va erny yvsr.`

Comment: Nail on the head @Kendra,  good stuff from Blue Raja too.

Comment: @ITAlex Despite the title of a recent puzzle of mine, I am a Pokemon Professor- You throw Pokemon in my face, I'll be darned if I don't at least come close. ;)

Comment: Thank you all, this was fun. You guys write faster than I can think

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Karma? Specifically, good Karma?

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> Buddhists believe in actions and consequences, yet they don't worship it.

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> Karma is eternal, since it is literally the consequences of actions. Bad Karma especially carves death, meaning bad things will happen to bad people. Ex: If you smoke, you will die of lung cancer, etc.

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

> Karma believers believe that doing good will result in good things being done to them. I am not sure what the other part of this line refers to though.

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> If Karma cries for you, it means that something good will happen in your life. I.E. you are being showered in good karma

Title: I am found everywhere and yet nowhere

> Karma isn't a physical thing, yet we can find it everywhere in daily life.

Comment: Its not, but that was a good guess.

Comment: Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'll add a hint after lunch :)

Answer (score 4):

2nd Attempt

Are you,

> Reincarnation?

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> One of the defining characteristics of Hinduism and Buddhism is reincarnation, but again, it is not worshipped

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> Reincarnation is eternal, but always occurs with death

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

> Reincarnation is an opportunity to start another life, maybe as a better person, job, career, etc. The opposite of reincarnation is just death, where the person sleeps in the grave for eternity

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> I'm not sure on this one, but if you're reincarnated, you'll be relieved that you won't have to die permanently?

Title: I am found everywhere and yet nowhere

> There are many claims of people being reincarnated, yet there's not really any proof that it actually exists.

Hint

> I am alive until I briefly am not. I believe this refers to the short waiting period between reincarnation.

Comment: much closer but no cigar, try thinking with the hint much closer to explicitly what it says

Comment: Is it Aveinan or Zbxfun (rot13)? Because i don't think those fit in with the clues as well.

Comment: Technically your answer is the answer for Line 1.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Spirit?

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> They believe in spirits but "[The Buddha has never advised His followers to worship such spirits](https://www.budsas.org/ebud/whatbudbeliev/306.htm)".

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> The body dies but the spirits stay alive forever.

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

> Good spirits and bad spirits?

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> I do not know.

I am alive until I briefly am not.

> They go out of the body?

Regarding the title

> Spirits are every where but you can't see them.

Answer (score 3):

Could be

> BUDDHA?

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> Buddhists don't actually 'worship' Buddha

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> Maybe related to reincarnation?

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

> Some people think Buddha grants wishes, but not sure about the second part

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> Weeping Buddha is supposed to take away the troubles of the world and grant peace in return

Hint

> I think the title of Buddha is given to a living person at times, but there is not always a living Buddha?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> H2O, possibly specifically a Desert Rain

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> H2O transforms between water itself, and vaporized water

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> The cycle for water is to fall, drain, eventually evaporate, and fall again. Death following you could be the dry spell between rains or the flash flood that can come from a desert rain.

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

> Dying of thirst, a desert rain would grant you a wish for drinkable water for sure. Below the crust of the earth molten lava is pretty much the opposite.

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> Desert Rains that come when you need it relieve you from both the dehydration you're likely suffering and from the hot sun itself, giving relief.

Title

> The vapor of water is found everywhere, but it's not very noticeable.

Comment: I love this answer, but I don't know what this has to do with Buddhism?

Comment: Nope. see the hints and one of the other questions has a partial answer for a line.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know My thinking was that H20 is "reincarnated" as vaporized water and then "reincarnated" into Rain. The same molecules undergo transformation of entirely different states and experiences. It's a stretch, but it made sense to me :p

Comment: Okay, I see that now.

Answer (score 1):

Second attempt

I realized this one fit better

Is it

> Budhha

Buddhists believe in, yet dont worship

> A new buddha is born after the previous one, in an eternal cycle

Some see as a wish granter

> granting the path to enlightenment, but the opposite (ignorance) lies beneath their thoughts

If i cry for you you will be relieved

> of your sins?

Hint:

> He is alive except for the brief time spent between the death of one and the birth of the next

Comment: I was probably writing my answer when he posted. didnt see. Look at the times

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Time

Buddhists believe in the

> kalachakra

Its cycle is eternal

some see

> time as a wish granter(Tasks get completed over time, also, the concept of illumination)

It cries for you,

> thinking of it as history remembering you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is

> Breath

I am the posterchild for what the Buddhists believe yet they don't worship me

> In Buddhism, breath remains perennial and can be seen as the "poster-child". In Maha Rahulovada Sutra,it is said that Buddha told his son, “This is the practice of mindfulness of breath, Rahula. This is how the sincere practice of mindfulness of breath is of great fruit, of great benefit. If mindfulness of breath is practiced continuously, then your last breath will be in knowing, not in unknowing.” Yet, at the same time, breath is not worshiped but practiced.

My cycle is eternal yet death follows me

> The cycle of breath is eternal with each breath being a new one when you inhale in but dies as you inhale out

Some see me as a wish granter and my opposite slumbers beneath

> As a breath renews,there is life. Once it stopped, one dies

If I cry for you, you will be relieved

> As we breathe in, the air goes through our nose and the breath "cries" so that our breath gets warm and wet to prevent irritation of the cell when the air gets into our lungs.

Title: I am found everywhere and yet nowhere

> Everyone you see you know they are breathing and you "find" them breathing but yet at the same time you cant see breath and wont think much of it

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as to avoid spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!